# Как отследить размер блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery, всплывающее-окно

Есть окошко и есть скрипт управляющий этим окошком:

```html
<div class="swiper-container"></div>

<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: false,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
  clickable: true,
      },
    });
</script>
```

Mожно ли сделать так, чтобы в момент раскрытия окошка во весь экран, менялся один из параметров скрипта, например `zoom` с `false` на `true`?

Пытался сделать через отслеживание размеров окна, но что то не выходит.
Или может, если это проще, запретить (сделать чтобы не срабатывал) двойной клик на этом окошке?

Answer (score 0):

Можно прочитать [документацию](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#zoom). Там есть хорошие методы и свойства: `mySwiper.zoom.enable();`, `mySwiper.zoom.disable();` и `mySwiper.zoom.toggle();`.
Можно попробовать написать так:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  zoom: false,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
})

function callZoom() {
  swiper.zoom.enabled = !swiper.zoom.enabled;
  console.log(swiper.zoom.enabled)
}
console.log(swiper.zoom.enabled)
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.0/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.0/js/swiper.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container" onclick="callZoom()">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую.

Comment: Оно вроде все как правильно, в консоли есть "true" но скрипт не работает. Т.е. сам zoom не работает. Такое ощущение что 'true' не попадает в нужное место.

Comment: Он в консоли выдает true. Может надо zoom: true?

Comment: Немного исправил.

Comment: Ок! Спасибо огромное! Завтра проверю, обязательно отпишусь. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: К сожалению то же самое. В консоли все нормально отрабатывает, но скрипт зум не запускает. Я для чистоты эксперимента все вынес в отдельный файл, ну чтоб не на готовом сайте пробовать где куча кода. Все равно, то же самое... Можете глянуть сами:
http://funbookforkids.com/admin/030-pagination.html

Comment: Вы хотите что-бы по клику на изображение открывалось модальное окно? Или я чего-то не догоняю

Comment: Да, а по двойному клику на изображение в модальном окне срабатывал зум. Но в обычном окне зум по двойному клику не нужен. Он там (в маленьком окне) вообще не нужен. Просто если я ставлю zoom: true он работает и в маленьком окне и в большом, а мне нужно только в большом.